# Not sure if set is bounded (compactness question) (Part B).

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

At first, I was positive that the subspace in part B was compact as it is both closed and bounded.  But then I was thinking about it, is the subspace actually bounded if x can continue forever although y is bounded below by the x axis?

Edit: I think I'm confusing myself.  A set is set to be bounded if f(x)<=M or f(x)>=M.  Thus it is bounded, can someone verify?  Thanks.

Comment: yeah b is definitely compact. Like you said, it is closed (since it includes $(0,0)$) and it is bounded (it is contained in the unit ball which is certainly bounded).

Comment: (0,0) is not a limit point however.  The set is closed because it contains all its limit points which are the set of points lying on  the downward sloping curve.  Is this correct?

Comment: I can find a ball around (0,0) that does not contain other elements from the set

Comment: Pick a ball centered at the origin with radius $r$. Because $r>0$, there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0<\frac{1}{n}<r$. In particular, you can "increase" $n$ enough such that $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$. That way, you can ensure $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ is contained in the ball and so $(0,0)$ cannot be isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Not compact as $(n,0)\in A$

2.Closed and bounded so compact.

3.Not compact as $(n,0)\in A$

4.Closed and bounded so compact.

Comment: Great, I got the same.  For a can I say not bounded so not compact.

Comment: @kemb;Yes you can

Comment: One last question, to make sure I'm doing this right.  For part B, (0,0) is not a limit point, but the set does indeed contain all its limit points, so it is closed.  is this correct?

Comment: For case 3 (or case c in the Q)  it is not clear whether $\phi$ is a fixed value  or not.. But regardless of that, we have $\|(r_n \cos n\phi, r_n \sin n \phi)\|=|r_n|$  so the set is unbounded..

Comment: @kemb; The elements are of the form $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ whose limit point is $(0,0)$ and that is contained in the set so the set is closed

Comment: To the proposer: For Part b,  $(0,0)$ is a limit point of $\{(1/n,1/n):n\in \Bbb N\}.$ It is the only non-isolated point of the subspace.

Comment: Yes, but we start from n=1 ...n=infinity.  If i draw a picture, it seems as if I can find a ball or neighborhood around (0,0), which doesn't contain other elements of the set.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet; $\phi$ is any  element of $[0,2\pi)$ I guess

Comment: @kemb; No you cant,You can try;By Archimedean Property there will exist an element of the  set in that ball

Comment: Any ball of radius $r>0$ centered at $(0,0)$ contains $(1/n,1/n) $ for every $n>1/r.$ Sketch  a picture of the set.

Comment: I see now.  But is (0,0) the only limit point?

Comment: See, i was drawing this as a graph, which is why I was confused:

Comment: I see, makes sense perfect sense now. I messed up.

Comment: Sometimes simpler things  are the easiest ti misunderstand. I usually try to  think about math  in pictures or geometrically to get an  overview of what's going on.

Comment: @kemb;If the answer serves you then please accept it